# creating user input grid-- JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

The goal is to allow user to enter a number `N`, and from that the program will create an N x N layout of buttons. The buttons don't have to do anything.

I'm trying to determine how to add all the objects to the GUI.  I've tried two approaches (shown below), without success. Any help would be appreciated.

**Unsuccessful Attempt 1:**

```
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class CheckerBoard extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setHgap(0);
        gridPane.setVgap(0);
        HBox pane = new HBox(15);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 650);
        Scene sceneGrid = new Scene(gridPane, 444, 444);
        Label layoutInput = new Label("Input number to create graph size:");
        TextField number = new TextField();


        Button createGraph = new Button("Create Board");


        createGraph.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> 
        {
            int size = Integer.parseInt(number.getText());
            //GridPane.setRowSpan(rowX, numb);
            //GridPane.setColumnSpan(colY, numb);
            Button [][] board = new Button [size][size];


            for (int row = 1; row < size; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 1; col < size; col++)
                {
                   Button fill = new Button();
                   Button button = new Button();
                   GridPane.setConstraints(button, 3, 1); 
                   board[row][col] = fill;



                    GridPane.setRowIndex(board[row][col], row);

                    //GridPane.setColumnIndex(button, col);

                    if ( row + col % 2 == 0 ) { //creates color pattern
                        button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
                    } else if (row + col % 2 == 1) {
                        button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
                    }

                    gridPane.getChildren().add(board[row][col]); 
                    gridPane.add(button, col, row);
                    pane.getChildren().add(gridPane);


                }
            }
        });
    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(gridPane);
    pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    pane.getChildren().addAll(layoutInput,number,createGraph);
    //pane.setPadding (top, right, bottom, left));

    pane.setPadding(new Insets(150, 0, 700, 0));


    primaryStage.setTitle("Checker grid");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    //displays contents

}
```

**Unsuccessful Attempt 2:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class gridfix extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage){
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();

        Label layoutInput = new Label("Input number to create graph size:");
        TextField number = new TextField();


        Button createGraph = new Button("Create Board");
        createGraph.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> 
        {
            int size = Integer.parseInt(number.getText());
            int BUTTON_PADDING = 0;
            int row = size;
            int col = size;


            grid.setPadding(new Insets(BUTTON_PADDING));
            grid.setHgap(BUTTON_PADDING);
            grid.setVgap(BUTTON_PADDING);

            for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < col; c++) {
                    int numbers = row * r + c;
                    Button button = new Button(String.valueOf(numbers));
                    grid.add(button, c, r);

                    if ( row + col % 2 == 1 ) 
                    { //creates color pattern
                            button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
                    } 
                    else if (row + col % 2 == 1) 
                    {
                            button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(grid);


        stage.setScene(new Scene(scrollPane));
        stage.show();
    }       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow I just figured it out, on my first code:

`Button createGraph = new Button("Create Board");

```
    createGraph.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> 
    {
        int size = Integer.parseInt(number.getText());
        //GridPane.setRowSpan(rowX, numb);
        //GridPane.setColumnSpan(colY, numb);
        Button [][] board = new Button [size][size];


        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < size; col++)
            {

               Button button = new Button();
              // GridPane.setConstraints(button, 3, 3); 


               board[row][col] = button;



                //GridPane.setRowIndex(board[row][col], row);


                //GridPane.setColumnIndex(board[row][col], col);

                if ( row + col % 2 == 0 ) { //creates color pattern
                    button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
                } else if (row + col % 2 == 1) {
                    button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
                }


                gridPane.add(button, col, row);



            }
        }
    });
pane.getChildren().add(gridPane); //this line of code was out of place and breaking everything
//ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(gridPane);
pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
pane.getChildren().addAll(layoutInput,number,createGraph);`
```

but my color pattern still is broken...it does the first few buttons and then stops. why?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use the loop variables to determine the color of the `Button` (error in second approach).
2. By just using the correct `add` method you can set the column/row index. there is no need to use `setRowIndex`, `setColumnIndex` in addition to that.
3. `%` is a multiplicative operator and has the precedence of such a operator, which means `row + col % 2 == 1` is equivalent to `row + (col % 2) == 1`; you need `(row + col) % 2 == 1` though.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();

    TextField number = new TextField();
    TextFormatter<Integer> formatter = new TextFormatter<>(new IntegerStringConverter());
    number.setTextFormatter(formatter);

    Button btn = new Button("Fill");
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        Integer i = formatter.getValue();
        if (i == null) {
            return;
        }

        final int n = i;
        grid.getChildren().clear();

        for (int r = 0; r < n; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
                Button button = new Button();
                button.setPrefSize(30, 30);
                button.setStyle("-fx-background-color:" + ((c + r) % 2 == 0 ? "red;" : "black;"));
                grid.add(button, c, r);
            }
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(new HBox(number, btn), grid), 500, 500);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```